# Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier 'g'

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Errors:

> Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier 'g' in /Users/julian/Sites/abc.php on line 23
>      Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier 'g' in /Users/julian/Sites/abc.php on line 23

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Crawler {
protected $markup = ”;
    public function __construct($uri) {
        $this->markup = $this->getMarkup($uri);
    }
    public function getMarkup($uri) {
        return file_get_contents($uri);
    }
    public function get($type) {
        $method = "_get_links";
        if (method_exists($this, $method))
                return call_user_method($method, $this);
             }
    }
    protected function _get_images() {
        if (!empty($this->markup)){
            preg_match_all(htmlspecialchars("<img([^>]+)/>i"), $this->markup, $images);
            return $images[1];
    }
    }
    protected function _get_links() {
        if (!empty($this->markup)){
            preg_match_all(htmlspecialchars("<a([^>]+)>(.*?)</a>/i"), $this->markup, $links);
            return $links;
        }
    }
}
$crawl = new Crawler("http://google.com/");
$images = $crawl->get(‘images’);
$links = $crawl->get(‘links’);
echo $links;
?>
```

Comment: could you indent your code so it's readable?

Comment: You haven't got delimiters on your regexp. Surround them with `/../`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are lacking delimiters. Correct regexes are:

```
↓             ↓
~<img([^>]+)/>~i
~<a([^>]+)>(.*?)</a>~i
↑                   ↑
```

But please be aware that it is generally not recommended to parse HTML using regular expressions. Instead you might consider using [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Note: *Unknown modifier 'g'* in PHP there is no [g modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) you just use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead of [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) if you want all matches.

Comment: "Though I do not recommend parsing HTML with regex (it is impossible)" is a pretty bold statement.  It is all completely situational whether you should be using regexp or DOM, and at the very least it is not even close to impossible.  Regexp is very very powerful for both parsing, segmenting, and validation when used correctly.

Comment: @Geoffrey: Don't think that I'm the typical idiot who says that you shouldn't use regex, just because he can't get the syntax. I am fully aware of the possibilities of regex: backreferences, lookahead, lookbehind and recursion are powerful tools. But the parsing algorithm defined by the HTML5 standard is by far too complicated to be covered by a regex. Vanilla XML probably may be parsed using regex correctly, but mostly broken HTML on most webpages can definitely not.

Comment: I never wanted to imply that your any kind of idiot.  I just wanted to make it clear to anyone that reads this, do not discount regex for your needs.  It is a very powerful, and an unvalidated opinion such as (it is impossible) without situational cases for both sides (because the DOM parser rocks too!) will lead future readers down one path when the other may work just as well or even better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Crawler {

protected $markup = ”;
public function __construct($uri) {
    $this->markup = $this->getMarkup($uri);
}
public function getMarkup($uri) {
    return file_get_contents($uri);
}
public function get($type) {
    $method = "_get_links";
    if (method_exists($this, $method)){

      return call_user_method($method, $this);
    }
}
protected function _get_images() {
    if (!empty($this->markup)){
        preg_match_all("/<img([^>]+)\/>/i", $this->markup, $images);
        return $images[1];
}
}
protected function _get_links() {
    if (!empty($this->markup)){
        preg_match_all("/<a([^>]+)\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/i", $this->markup, $links);
        return $links;
    }
}
}
$crawl = new Crawler("http://google.com/");
$images = $crawl->get(‘images’);
$links = $crawl->get(‘links’);
print_r($links);
```

Comment: … and don't use `htmlspecialchars()` unless you really search for '&lt;img ...&gt;' (which you won't find on Googles frontpage btw).